# Is it possible to send AT commands over BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, hfp

I want to accept, end and reject incoming calls when my Android phone is connected to my bluetooth enabled device over BLE. I understand that this is possible by sending AT commands over HFP.

Is it possible to send AT commands over BLE as well?